# Group and find if there any TRUE

Tags: r

I have a df like this

```
test <- 
data.frame(type=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c"),
           cond=c(F,F,F,T,F,F,F,F,T,F,T,F))
```

and I want to group by 'type' and then get if any value in 'cond' is true. In that example, types a and c has at least one T, and b not, so my desired output is something like this

| type | cond |
| --- | --- |
| a | T |
| b | F |
| c | T |

Thanks

Comment: `transform(test, result = ave(cond, type,  FUN = any))` in Base R

Comment: `dplyr::mutate(test, result = any(cond), .by = type)`